# Unneeded Tag - Extension-Field

Tags: discussion, tagging

I propose the removal of the tag extension-field. There are currently a grand total of 39 questions tagged with it so it would not take long to remove it. Furthermore I don't think the tag is particularly useful, field-theory or galois-theory almost always suffices. See for yourself [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/extension-field).https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/extension-field

Comment: Often the questions covered by tag a are a subset of the questions covered by tag b, but tag a is still useful to filter the questions further when searching for a particular topic.

Comment: This could be a post in the tagging thread  http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1363/tag-merging-and-synonyms (not necessary to open a thread for each tag... there are so many of those).

Comment: Seems to me that we could profitably just make it an synonym for field-theory. Is there any nontrivial part of field theory that is _not_ about field extensions anyway?

Comment: I share your feelings about this tag. If judged prudent/helpful, I could volunteer to do a retagging-spree getting rid of it.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think the tag should be removed: there is an important difference between a field extension of a field $k$ and an arbitrary algebra over  $k$.
For example a commutative $k$-algebra  $A$ is defined to be separable  if for any field extension $E$ of $k$  the $k$-algebra $E\otimes_k A$ is reduced.
Extensions  $E$ of $k$ play a vital role here in the study of $k$-algebras which need not be extensions of $k$: for example it is enough to test reducedness for $E=k^{p^{-\infty}}$, a perfect  closure of $k$.
Also transcendental field extensions are quite important in algebraic geometry and they have nothing to do with Galois theory, so that the tag galois-theory would not be a suitable replacement.
And let me also mention, as an answer to Henning's question,  that there *are* non-trivial results of field theory which are not about extension fields: for example that the tensor products of two reduced algebras over a perfect field is reduced, a fact that was asked about [on our site](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/308015/how-to-show-the-tensor-product-of-reduced-k-algebra-must-be-reduced).

Comment: I understand your point. But that's certainly not how the tag is used on this site. It tends to be used in such questions as show that $[\mathbb Q(\sqrt{3},\sqrt{2}):\mathbb Q]=4$.